# How can DISTINCT values outside of a GROUP BY be counted without using sub-queries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.6

I am refactoring some business logic that we normally do as nightly processes in Java, and am now attempting to move into PostgreSQL as a set of materialized views. I've reduced the problem to its essentials, which results in the three tables below (`category_source` ~10 rows, `category` ~100k rows, `category_tags` ~10M rows).

The logic is fairly simple: for each `Source`, sum the values of each `Tag` in the set of `Categories` in that `Source`, and divide each of those sums by the total number of `Categories` in the `Source`.

```
--DROP TABLE category_tags;
--DROP TABLE category;
--DROP TABLE category_source;

CREATE TABLE category_source
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE category
(
  label text NOT NULL,
  source integer NOT NULL REFERENCES category_source(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (label)
);

CREATE TABLE category_tags
(
  category text NOT NULL REFERENCES category(label),
  tag text NOT NULL,
  rank real NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (category,tag)
);

-- Load sample data.
INSERT INTO category_source VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO category_source VALUES (2);

INSERT INTO category VALUES ('C3035240',1);
INSERT INTO category VALUES ('C3035245',1);
INSERT INTO category VALUES ('C3035250',2);

INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035240','test',24.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035240','sample',24.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035240','method',20.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035240','variety',18.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035240','explanation',15.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035245','test',20.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035245','extra',21.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035245','method',20.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035245','sample',18.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035245','question',15.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035250','method',10.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035250','explanation',8.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035250','test',6.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035250','question',5.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035250','sample',2.00);
INSERT INTO category_tags VALUES ('C3035250','variety',4.00);
```

*Query 1* here gets most of the way there, but the `source_category_count` column contains the number of `Categories` that the `Tag` is in for the `Source` (varies), whereas what I really want is the total number of `Categories` in the `Source`.

```
SELECT category_source.id,category_tags.tag,
       SUM(category_tags.rank) AS tag_total,
       COUNT(category.label) AS source_category_count,
       SUM(category_tags.rank)/COUNT(category.label) AS source_tag_rank
 FROM
  category_source,category,category_tags
 WHERE
  category_source.id=category.source
  AND category.label=category_tags.category
 GROUP BY category_source.id,category_tags.tag ORDER BY category_source.id,tag_total DESC;

 id |     tag     | tag_total | source_category_count | source_tag_rank
----+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------
  1 | test        |        44 |                     2 |              22
  1 | sample      |        42 |                     2 |              21
  1 | method      |        40 |                     2 |              20
  1 | extra       |        21 |                     1 |              21
  1 | variety     |        18 |                     1 |              18
  1 | explanation |        15 |                     1 |              15
  1 | question    |        15 |                     1 |              15
  2 | method      |        10 |                     1 |              10
  2 | explanation |         8 |                     1 |               8
  2 | test        |         6 |                     1 |               6
  2 | question    |         5 |                     1 |               5
  2 | variety     |         4 |                     1 |               4
  2 | sample      |         2 |                     1 |               2
(13 rows)
```

*Query 2* below produces the results I am really looking for:

```
SELECT q1.*,q2.source_category_count,q1.tag_total/q2.source_category_count AS tag_source_rank FROM
(
  SELECT category_source.id AS source,category_tags.tag,SUM(category_tags.rank) AS tag_total
   FROM category_source
   INNER JOIN category ON (category_source.id=category.source)
   INNER JOIN category_tags ON (category.label=category_tags.category)
   GROUP BY category_source.id,category_tags.tag
) q1,
(
  SELECT source,COUNT(category) AS source_category_count FROM category GROUP BY source
) q2
 WHERE q1.source=q2.source
 ORDER BY source,tag_source_rank DESC
;

     source |     tag     | tag_total | source_category_count | tag_source_rank
    --------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------
          1 | test        |        44 |                     2 |              22
          1 | sample      |        42 |                     2 |              21
          1 | method      |        40 |                     2 |              20
          1 | extra       |        21 |                     2 |            10.5
          1 | variety     |        18 |                     2 |               9
          1 | explanation |        15 |                     2 |             7.5
          1 | question    |        15 |                     2 |             7.5
          2 | method      |        10 |                     1 |              10
          2 | explanation |         8 |                     1 |               8
          2 | test        |         6 |                     1 |               6
          2 | question    |         5 |                     1 |               5
          2 | variety     |         4 |                     1 |               4
          2 | sample      |         2 |                     1 |               2
    (13 rows)
```

*Query 3* produces equivalent results using `WITH x () SELECT ...`:

```
WITH category_counts AS
(
  SELECT source,COUNT(category) AS source_category_count FROM category GROUP BY source
) 
SELECT category_counts.source,category_tags.tag,
       SUM(category_tags.rank) AS tag_total,
       COUNT(category.label) AS source_category_freq,
       category_counts.source_category_count,
       SUM(category_tags.rank)/category_counts.source_category_count AS source_tag_rank
 FROM category_counts
 INNER JOIN category ON (category_counts.source=category.source)
 INNER JOIN category_tags ON (category.label=category_tags.category)
 GROUP BY category_counts.source,category_counts.source_category_count,category_tags.tag ORDER BY category_counts.source,tag_total DESC;

 source |     tag     | tag_total | source_category_freq | source_category_count | source_tag_rank
--------+-------------+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------
      1 | test        |        44 |                    2 |                     2 |              22
      1 | sample      |        42 |                    2 |                     2 |              21
      1 | method      |        40 |                    2 |                     2 |              20
      1 | extra       |        21 |                    1 |                     2 |            10.5
      1 | variety     |        18 |                    1 |                     2 |               9
      1 | explanation |        15 |                    1 |                     2 |             7.5
      1 | question    |        15 |                    1 |                     2 |             7.5
      2 | method      |        10 |                    1 |                     1 |              10
      2 | explanation |         8 |                    1 |                     1 |               8
      2 | test        |         6 |                    1 |                     1 |               6
      2 | question    |         5 |                    1 |                     1 |               5
      2 | variety     |         4 |                    1 |                     1 |               4
      2 | sample      |         2 |                    1 |                     1 |               2
(13 rows)
```

Although I have two working queries that both produce the results I am looking for, I am unsatisfied with using two subqueries over tables of this size (I have not yet loaded in all of my data or done any performance testing, I am simply working on this test case at the moment).

I feel that the value for `source_category_count` that I am looking for is buried somewhere in *Query 1* and I just don't know how to access it.

Another alternative I am investigating is `COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY category_source)`, but I do not have a working query for that method at the moment.

Is there a simpler query that will produce the same results as *Query 2* or *Query 3* (i.e., a modification of *Query 1*)?

**Update:** Added a second working query.

Comment: why are you writing sql-89 style joins

Comment: @EvanCarroll Because of the "[heinous syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/334701/2074605)" and frequently encountering [this error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/190642/68823).

Comment: you don't have to use the USING clause. It's great practice though. It forces you away from the convention you're adopting here with `id` which is pretty lame. The standard pushes for globally unique table-identifiers with `USING`

Comment: And, I agree NATURAL JOINS are a horrible idea, so don't use them. That has nothing to do with SQL-92 syntax.

Comment: It's not horrible, it's `natural` ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ `HEINOUS JOIN USING (...)`. Anyway, I revised my queries to use SQL-92 joins, except for join between the sub-queries, which I'm unclear on the most appropriate form.

Comment: @vallismortis I went ahead and tried to answer that question too, if you want a better answer for it then the others https://stackoverflow.com/a/47720615/124486

Comment: What exactly does `source_category_count` count? The number of distinct `category` values in category table or the number of distinct `category` values in the `category join category_tags`? Because the two numbers may differ (if there are categories that do not appear in category_tags).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ `source_category_count` is the number of categories associated with a source. Because it is n-to-1, `SELECT source,COUNT(category) AS source_category_count FROM category GROUP BY source;` will always produce the same result as `SELECT source,COUNT(DISTINCT(category)) AS source_category_count FROM category GROUP BY source;`.

Comment: @vallismortis *"heinous syntax"* is just an opinion. Did you notice that that answer has 7 downvotes?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What if there was an additional row (`INSERT INTO category VALUES ('C444444',1);`), with no related rows in `category_tags`. Would that change the results? (change some 2s to 3s?)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, the count is the number of categories per source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining straight to the `category` table you can join instead to a subquery with a window function.  You only query the table once and also get your end result.

```
SELECT category_source.id AS source,
    category_tags.tag,
    SUM(category_tags.rank) AS tag_total,
    MAX(category_source_count) AS source_category_count,
    SUM(category_tags.rank)/MAX(category_source_count) AS source_tag_rank
FROM category_source
   INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT label, source, 
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY source) category_source_count 
            FROM category
        ) AS category ON category_source.id=category.source
   INNER JOIN category_tags ON category.label=category_tags.category
GROUP BY category_source.id,category_tags.tag 
ORDER BY category_source.id,tag_total DESC;
```

Comment: Ok, now this is closer to what I'm looking for. This produces the expected results and uses one fewer sub-query. I still feel that there should be a more direct way to get to the category count without a sub-select, but given the current limitations in PostgreSQL, this looks like it is possibly the most direct solution to the query. I compared the execution plan of this query to Query 3 in the question, and the run-time for this one is slightly worse, but that could change when I run a test against the larger tables.

Comment: @vallismortis I imagine query 3 would be even faster if you didn't use a CTE.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Isn't that essentially what this answer is? The CTE produces a very small table, so I don't think it adds much overhead. I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> whereas what I really want is the total number of Categories in the Source.

You're grouping by `category_source.id, category_tags.tag` -- that means you can never say you want "*in the*" without including that group, which in your case includes tags. **The two sub-selects with different `GROUP BY`'s is the accepted method of doing this**, but there are other options to generate the data you want, like `GROUPING SETS`; however, the result won't look the same.

```
SELECT
        c.label,
        tag,
        SUM(ct.rank) AS tag_total,
        COUNT(c.label) AS source_category_count
FROM category AS c
JOIN category_tags AS ct
        ON (ct.category=c.label)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((c.label, ct.tag), (c.label))

;
  label   |     tag     | tag_total | source_category_count 
----------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------
 C3035240 | explanation |        15 |                     1
 C3035240 | method      |        20 |                     1
 C3035240 | sample      |        24 |                     1
 C3035240 | test        |        24 |                     1
 C3035240 | variety     |        18 |                     1
 C3035240 |             |       101 |                     5
 C3035245 | extra       |        21 |                     1
 C3035245 | method      |        20 |                     1
 C3035245 | question    |        15 |                     1
 C3035245 | sample      |        18 |                     1
 C3035245 | test        |        20 |                     1
 C3035245 |             |        94 |                     5
 C3035250 | explanation |         8 |                     1
 C3035250 | method      |        10 |                     1
 C3035250 | question    |         5 |                     1
 C3035250 | sample      |         2 |                     1
 C3035250 | test        |         6 |                     1
 C3035250 | variety     |         4 |                     1
 C3035250 |             |        35 |                     6
(19 rows)
```

You can see here we have two `GROUP BY`s in the same `SELECT` and you can see how SQL displays such a query.

As a side note, I would suggest never using SQL-89 joins. There is no reason for it. Writes your joins explicitly with `[INNER] JOIN`.

Comment: As you recommended, I revised my queries to use SQL-92 joins, except in the case of the sub-selects. I haven't used `GROUPING SETS` before, but I am now investigating it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun**<sup>*</sup>**, the query could be done with no subqueries - if Postgres had implemented `DISTINCT` in window aggregates:

```
select distinct
    source,
    tag,
    sum(rank) over (partition by source, tag) as tag_total,
    count(*) over (partition by source, tag) as count,
    count(distinct category) over (partition by source) as count_category,
    sum(rank) over (partition by source, tag)
    / count(distinct category) over (partition by source) as avg_rank
from 
    category c 
    join category_tags ct
        on label = category
order by 
    source,
    tag_total desc ;
```

Tested in [dbfiddle.uk (Oracle)](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f6abf5efccfb9b744362e82d3cabf138), it just works.

In **[dbfiddle.uk (Postgres)](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=22a1e29b8e9b18394457b5fdcee59816)**, gives the error:

> ```
> ERROR:  DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions  
> LINE 6:     count(distinct category) over (partition by source) as c...  
>             ^
> ```

**<sup>*</sup>** I wouldn't recommend using the above method anyway, even if the syntax was available. The need for two different aggregation sets in the same result require to use two different `OVER ()` expressions and the use of `SELECT DISTINCT`. All in, is probably a recipe for mediocre efficiency.

A query with 2 derived tables and then joining them, would probably be more efficient.

Comment: I upvoted this, because (a) it's useful to point out that there are better methods of doing this that aren't *yet* supported, (b) when I do this others they should react the same way. wink wink mysql, and sql-server borg =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a starting point ...

```
select distinct
  CS.id
, CT.tag
, sum( CT.rank ) over ( partition by C.source, CT.tag order by C.source) as tag_total
, count( CT.category ) over ( partition by C.source, CT.tag order by C.source) as count
, ( sum( CT.rank ) over ( partition by C.source, CT.tag order by C.source) )
  / ( count( CT.category ) over ( partition by C.source, CT.tag order by C.source) 
  ) as tag_source_rank
from category_source CS
  join category C on CS.id = C.source
  join category_tags CT on C.label = CT.category
order by CS.id, tag_total desc
;
```

-- Result

```
 id |     tag     | tag_total | count | tag_source_rank 
----+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------------
  1 | test        |        44 |     2 |              22
  1 | sample      |        42 |     2 |              21
  1 | method      |        40 |     2 |              20
  1 | extra       |        21 |     1 |              21
  1 | variety     |        18 |     1 |              18
  1 | explanation |        15 |     1 |              15
  1 | question    |        15 |     1 |              15
  2 | method      |        10 |     1 |              10
  2 | explanation |         8 |     1 |               8
  2 | test        |         6 |     1 |               6
  2 | question    |         5 |     1 |               5
  2 | variety     |         4 |     1 |               4
  2 | sample      |         2 |     1 |               2
(13 rows)
```

[Dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=64b0ec70073fa286aa117fdff8e2d4bb) (Postgresql 9.5)

Comment: I see where you're going with this, and I was on the same path but haven't found the right partition to get that 4th column to produce the category count over the source (see results from Query 2 and Query 3 for the "correct" result set).